# How to tag satellite pagers?

Tags: discussion, tags

How should questions about satellite pagers such as Garmin InReach, Zoleo, or Somewear be tagged?  We have the tag [satellite-phones](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellite-phones).  Although all of the above use the Iridium satellite phone network to communicate, they're not actually phones as they can not be used for voice calls (and Zoleo and Somewear need to pair with a smartphone to send text messages).  Do we need a tag for satellite pagers, or do we broaden [satellite-phones](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellite-phones) to also include satellite pagers?

I think InReach has been around since 2016, whereas Zoleo and Somewear are even newer (I think introduced in 2020, and only in limited parts of the world as of 2022), so TGO SE is considerably older than any of them.

Comment: I guess the key question is how many questions do we have on them, and are those different to the ones tagged satellite-phones. If so, let's use a new tag.

Comment: In my opinion, the technology used for a certain electronics equipment is less relevant than `how to` and `when to` use such an equipment. In this case, if the question dwells around what backbone technology these equipment use, rather than practical on-field use case, then we'll have see if it really fits at TGO. If the question fits well with TGO, then as you thought of earlier that we should broaden the satellite-phones tag to may be satellite-equipment or something similar.

Comment: @WedaPashi Maybe `satellite-communication`?  The tag `satellite-equipment` would include GPS, which I think is sufficiently different that it should be covered by a different tag.

Comment: @gerrit -- Yes, `satellite-communication` sounds correct.